# Deleting a corrupted Site Collection

Tags: 2013, site-collection, content-database

I have a site collection which is corrupted, it was not deleted correctly and now I cannot fully remove it.

It does not appear in the Central Admin, but it does with Powershell. Compatibility level appears empty. 
Somehow, the database where this site collection was, is also corrupted. It does not appear in the Central Admin, but it does via Powershell. I can't delete it either.

Querying $site.contentDatabase returns nothing, it looks like there is no connection between the site collection and the database.

I can't create the database again with the same name, or even delete the web application where this site collection was. Is there any way to force delete the site collection and the database?

Answer (score 3):

there are couple of Methods to remove the orphan site.

Method 1 :

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://siteurl
$siteId = $site.Id
$siteDatabase = $site.ContentDatabase
$siteDatabase.ForceDeleteSite($siteId, $false, $false)
```

**Method 2, try to use stsadm.**

Try to use Old Fashioned Stsadm command.

```
stsadm -o deletesite -force -siteid e2a114b8-80c9-41f6-87bf-3feddf2ad9b6 -databaseserver DS1 -databasename DB1
```

[Deleting the Orphan Sites in the Sharepoint](http://krossfarm.com/?p=51)

Comment: Thanks but site.contentDatabase returns nothing. There is no database assigned to the site collection.

Comment: check the blog their are 4 methods mentioned in it, try those

Answer (score 1):

did you try to play with : Get-SPDeletedSite and Remove-SPDeletedSite ?

Comment: Yes, no deleted site unfortunately

Comment: Ok so... I suppose that you see the site collection using Get-SPSite?
What if you try to delete it using Remove-SPSite? Any Errors? Do you check for orphans items ?

Comment: I can't delete it either with Remove-SPSite.
Remove-SPSite : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is it possible to check for orphan items somehow?

Comment: $CDBs = Get-SPContentDatabase
ForEach ($CDB in $CDBs)
{
    Write-Host "Detecting Orphans for " $CDB.Name
    $CDB.Repair($false)
}

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144701/how-to-identify-orphaned-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013-content-database

Comment: Get-SPContentDatabase does not return this database. However Get-SPDatabase does. 

Using this code on the failing database generates an error: 
Exception calling "Repair" with "1" argument(s): "<nativehr>0x80004003</nativeh
r><nativestack></nativestack>"
At line:1 char:1
+ $cdb.Repair($false)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

If the database still showing in get-spdatabase then you have to delete the orphaned database first, see [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30558.sharepoint-2013-deleting-orphaned-sharepoint-databases.aspx) post

```
$dbs = Get-SPDatabase 
$dbs | ?{$_.Exists -eq $false}  | %{Write-Host "DB"$_.Name"does not exist. Deleting and cleaning up references." -f red; $_.Delete();$_.Unprovision()}
```